# Returning value from function to main

Tags: function

I am trying to take a value from the function, and use it in the main.  For the life of me I cannot figure it out.  My code looks like this.

```
def randPoint(win):
point1 = random.randrange(0,600)
point2 = random.randrange(0,200)
rPoint = Point(point1,point2)

return rPoint

def main():
win=GraphWin("Bounce n Score!", 600, 600)
win.setCoords(0,0, 900, 900)

intro(win)
circle(win)
randPoint(win)
makeBig(win,rPoint)
```

I want to be able to take this point and get the X, and Y and use it in another function. Functions are kicking my butt right now.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like randPoint does anything with it's 'win' argument?

rPoint doesn't exist in main, only in randPoint.

It seems like you may be able to get away with makeBig(win,randPoint()) ?

I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony's answer should work. This is a bit clearer, but same thing:

```
def main():
...
    rPoint=randPoint(win)
    makeBig(win,rPoint)
```

A `function` returns a `value` when you call it. You need to grab that value, either explicitly like I did,   `rPoint=randPoint(win)` or implicitly, like @Anthony did (the function call itself returns the value set in your return statement ) to use it in the calling function.

When you declare `rPoint = Point(point1,point2)` in `randPoint()` its scope is local - only visible within that function: `randPoint()`. When you write `return rPoint` you are sending the value of `rPoint` back to the caller using that function.